# How to set multiple conditions in if else statement, php

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to set a if statement(s) for a self-processing form that checks if the user entered a positive whole number for quantity. This would be the following conditions:

is_numeric

is_int

and > 0

I've read that I can use || and && to set multiple conditions in a single if function, however it's not working because when I typed "-1" or "jkgh" as quantity, it still printed the table row.

If statement:

```
    if (is_numeric($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) || is_int($_POST['qty_entered'][0]) || $_POST['qty_entered'][0] > 0) {
    print "'<tr><td>' test '</td>'";
```

Thanks!

Comment: `||` stands for **OR**, `&&` stands for **AND**. Once you know that, just try to phrase your conditions and replace with appropriate symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code says *if the input is a number, or is an integer, or is just greater than zero, then it's alright*, not if *all* of those conditions are true.

You probably mean `&&` to force all of those to match instead of any one of them with `||`.

When you define this sort of test you'll want to formalize it in a function so that the intent of your code is clear:

```
function is_sufficiently_numeric($v) {
  return is_numeric($v) && is_int($v) && $v > 0;
}
```

Then your code becomes more self-explanatory, and as a bonus, less verbose.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I have another issue, I want to display a second table after the submit button is pressed, however, there also must be no errors in the quantity entered. Currently I have: if (array_key_exists ('submit_button', $_POST)) && $errors = false{
    print "Invoice <br> <table style='border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center'
 However, it gives me an error when I add in the && $errors = false

Comment: Hold on there. Stack Overflow is all about addressing one question at a time. That sounds like a well-defined problem, so instead of cramming it in a comment here, hopen up a new question. Having questions focused on a singular problem helps keep them narrow enough in scope they might help other people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, I will. Thank you so much for the help!